# Cross-compile/Recompile an ActiveX for mobile devices

Tags: vb6, activex, mobile-phones, cross-compiling

In our project, we have a lot of ActiveX controls written in VB6. On big (x86) computers it works very well. These controls are hosted on website. And mobile users also wants to use it.
So is there any possible solution to recompile/cross-compile an .ocx and make .cab file to works under ARM architecture?
Or maybe I can emulate x86 architecture on mobile phones/PDAs?

Mateusz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to take a control written in VB6 and run it on a device with an ARM processor (via cross-compiling, emulation or otherwise).

Your best route is to rewrite your application in something that targets both x86 and the ARM mobile platform of your choice (one of java/j2me, .net framework/compact framework, flash, C/C++, etc) or just make your application run at the server and expose it via the web

Comment: There is always a way, via virtualbox, Windows 98 emulator, conversion or otherwise. The question really is, how to do so *realistically*